# Magento 2 How to apply filters for layered navigation Using REST API

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, layered-navigation, magento2.2.2

I want to apply filters for layered navigation using REST API. If I send color=5 then in category page it is displaying 2 products so how to get that data in API response?

Comment: You are magento frontend or Rest Api?

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks for your reply I need in Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the product lists Using SearchCriteria in REST API.

```
http://local-magento.com/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=<category-id>&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=<color-id>&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

where "category-id" is Store category Id. Example : 4
"color-id" is color id of products: Ex: 5

or you have to customize that functionality using own custom API.

Implement the Magento Default Rest API according to our own requirements

```
http://local-magento.com/rest/V1/categories/4/products
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but hot apply filters as I explained above with an attribute, for example, color = red. when I click a red color in the frontend I got 2 configurable products but in REST API how to get that functionality.

Comment: answer updated. please check it

Comment: Yes, There is no default Magento functionality on this and I need to work on custom API functionality. Do u have any idea on this of applying filters using REST API??